# how to access rendered json objects in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I want to access the following array @names in my java script as json format.
So in my controller I have this code:

```
def new 
    @release = Release.new
     @names=User.select(:name).where("name LIKE 'sr%'")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @release }
      format.json { render :json =>{ :data1 => @names} } 
    end
  end
```

Please let me know how to access the data1 in my view file and how to pass the value to the javascript function .

Thanks,
Ramya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use jQuery, you can do:

```
$.getJSON('users/new.json', function(data) {
  console.log(data); //you'll find your json here
});
```

---

You do :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(function(){ 
    $.getJSON('releases/new.json', function(data1) { 
      alert("inside getJson"); alert(data1); console.log(data1); 
    }); 
});
```

But you should do:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $.getJSON('releases/new.json', function(data1) { 
    alert("inside getJson"); alert(data1); console.log(data1); 
  }); 
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(function(){ 
    $.getJSON('releases/new.json', function(data1) { 
      alert("inside getJson"); alert(data1); console.log(data1);
    }); 
  })(); 
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for answering me . I have placed the code inside. The control doesn't go to the "getJSON function"$(document).ready(function() {
$(function(){
$.getJSON('releases/new.json', function(data1) {  
alert("inside getJson"); 
alert(data1);
console.log(data1); 
}); 
  });

Comment: Hi sorry I missed to noticed the error in the ruby file. I am getting an error : Started GET "/releases/releases/new.json" for 172.30.11.164 at Mon Jan 02 17:08:13 +0530 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/releases/releases/new.json"):

So What do I have to add in the routes file

Comment: Mmmm, try to replace: `$.getJSON('releases/new.json'` with `$.getJSON('/releases/new.json'` there is just a `/` to add.

Comment: Thanks a ton.That worked .But inside on trying to print data1 I am getting [object Object] and not any values

Comment: thats an expected behavior in alert box, you should check your js debugging console.

Comment: showing in the console as Object {user={...}user Object { name="sramya"} and so on.My requirement is to use this json in the autocomplete function.So I gave this inside the getJSON function.$('#release_tester_tokens').autocomplete{source:data1});   I am getting this error in the console this.source is not a function
_search()jquery...0900941 (line 5216)
value = "a"
search()jquery...0900941 (line 5209)
value = "a"
event = Object { originalEvent=Event keydown, type="keydown", more...}
(?)()jquery...0900941 (line 5014)
[Break On This Error] this.source( { term: value }, this.response );

Answer (score 2):

instead of `http://domain/releases/1` you type `http://domain/releases/1.json` and you will get the data parsed as json!